# Using Material Design Components in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I'm building my first app with Android studio and I'd like to use Material Design components such as cards in it.

I think I know how to add these by writing code, but I was wondering, is it possible to add cardview, recycleview etc. in design tab's palette somehow?

Comment: If you learning you should give first preference to doing it via code instead of drag and drop

Comment: You should install the Android Design Support Library for extra material design components such as Cardview. Use gradle : 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I used Android Studio to create material design apps, I always created the card through xml. It is then displayed correctly in the design view. However the widgets on the left hand side of the design view are only simple images, which are part of the actual Android API (do not need any extra references like in your case). To add a card to your page use the following xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_initial_background"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
        >

    //add any widgets which you want inserted in the card here
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Code has been taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/samples/CardView/res/layout/fragment_card_view.html).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The link is dead.